# Parse codeigniter view in javascript

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Ok, here is the problem:

I have a search that gets results from server through ajax and I need to be able to include a view file with variable for each result.

Each result block would be included normally like this:

```
{include file={#modules_box#} foo="bar"}
```

How can I parse a codeigniter template file in javascript to pass correct 'foo' and show the results properly? I can go through each object in included template and replace those with search results but it is lengthy ('foo' is an object) and it creates lengthy task if modules_box view is updated later on.

Or am I looking from very wrong point of view? Should it be done differently?

Comment: You are getting the results in json format and need to format them in a view to pass them to the browser? Or it's the other way around.. You want to pass results in json to your javascript?

Comment: @chaft I am getting the results in json and I want to format them in a view

Comment: Then you need to either do some fancy string manipulation in js, or you need to rewrite the view in a js-friendly template.

Comment: @swatkins Don't wanna do lengthy string manipulation in js. Could you point to an example for writing a js-friendly template?

Comment: http://www.handlebarsjs.com/ - https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/ - http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I have solved it using:

[Smarty Parser for Javascript](http://code.google.com/p/jsmart/)
and
[php.js](http://code.google.com/p/jsmart/)